# Unable to get cameras list in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm making an app and I want to get a list of all connected cameras to my pc in a select tag and when I choose one of these I want to open live stream of that camera on screen. I tried to many things bust failed to get the list of connected cameras. Anyone have any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is web-based, you can leverage the getUserMedia API. This API allows users to grant permission to access their camera and provides a stream for manipulation. However, this approach has limitations:
It only works in modern browsers with proper support.
It might not be suitable for desktop applications outside of web browsers.

Comment: No I'm making an offline desktop app, and I don't want my app to ask for permissions like browsers do..